# Which dg-algebras have minimal model which is $A_{fin}$?

Tags: differential-graded-algebras, a-infinity-algebras

$A_{fin}$ algebra it is $A_\infty$ algebra with $m_n = 0$ for $n >> 0$ and $A^i = 0$ for $|i| >> 0$.

Suppose that we have (compact) dg-algebra $A$, we can build $A_\infty$ minimal model on $H^*(A)$ what we can say about $A$ if we know that minimal model is actually $A_{fin}$?

Or, in another direction, let we have $A_{fin}$ algebra $B$ what we can say about dg-algebra $cobar(bar(B))$?